# How can I get Regex to remove redundancies and call itself again?

Tags: python, regex

I have a simple function which when given an input like (x,y), it will return {{x},{x,y}}.

In the cases that x=y, it naturally returns {{x},{x,x}}.

I can't figure out how to get Regex to substitute 'x' in place of 'x,x'. But even if I could figure out how to do this, the expression would go from {{x},{x,x}} to {{x},{x}}, which itself would need to be substituted for {{x}}.

The closest I have gotten has been:

```
re.sub('([0-9]+),([0-9]+)',r'\1',string)
```

But this function will also turn {{x},{x,y}} into {{x},{x}}, which is not desired. Also you may notice that the function searches for numbers only, which is fine because I really only intend to be using numbers in the place of x and y; however, if there is a way to get it to work with any letter as well (lower case or capital) the would be even more ideal.

Note also that if I give my original function (x,y,z) it will read it as ((x,y),z) and thus return {{{{x},{x,y}}},{{{x},{x,y}},z}}, thus in the case that x=y=z, I would want to be able to have a Regex function call itself repeatedly to reduce this to {{{{x}}},{{{x}},x}} instead of {{{{x},{x,x}}},{{{x},{x,x}},x}}.

If it helps at all, this is essentially an attempt at making a translation (into sets) using the [Kuratowski definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition) of an ordered pair.

Comment: can you post a test string?

Comment: @oppressionslayer You mean what the output is on a particular string? When string = {{1},{1,1}} the code above returns {{1},{1}}. When the string is {{1},{1,2}} the code above also returns {{1},{1}}.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good task for Regex. In fact, why are you using strings at all instead of actual data structures? You can't nest `set`s but you can nest `frozenset`s.

Comment: It should repeat matches, do you want your sub to be instead of r'\1' to be r'\g<0>'

Comment: @AlexHall When I say 'set' I don't really mean 'set', I just mean anything that has the form {a, b, c, ..., z}. Since I don't need to do any set operations I figured strings would do just fine. But if not, what would I need to accomplish this task?

Comment: @Nika I don't know what you mean by accomplishing a test. Why not just make your function return `frozenset([frozenset([x]), frozenset([x, y])])`?

Comment: @AlexHall is there a way to translate `frozenset([frozenset([x]), frozenset([x, y])])` into the *string* `{{x},{x,y}}`?

Comment: @Nika again, is there a good reason that your final result needs to be a string? But yes, just take the `str()` of your frozenset and just replace `frozenset([` with `{` and `])` with `}`.

Comment: @AlexHall Oh, I guess that could work then. I wanted it to be strings originally because I have another function which takes strings of the form `{{0},{{0,1}}` and replaces 0 with {} and 1 with {{}}, and other numbers with other arrangements of left and right curly brackets, so that at the end I can turn something like (0,1,2) into a string consisting of only left and right curly brackets.

Comment: @nika, so we can help you more can you check out https://regex101.com/r/Yl1IJv/1/   You can modify that with inputs and hit save and share here again so we can see what your looking it, i think it would help as i'd like to help you solve the issue but i think i need something visual from regex101 to help see what your referring too.

Comment: @oppressionslayer Ok, I played around in https://regex101.com/r/Yl1IJv/2 and saved the result. You will notice that it turns {{1},{1,1}} into {{1},{1}}, which is good. But it doesn't turn {{1},{1}} into {{1}}.

Comment: @oppressionslayer Played around even more and now I have https://regex101.com/r/Yl1IJv/3 which will both turn {{1},{1,1}} into {{1},{1}} and will turn {{1},{1}} into {{1}} but will not turn {{1},{1,1}} into {{1}}.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Yl1IJv/4 extends the previous one by working for words as well as numbers. But the problem from the comment above still stands.

Comment: Is it not possible to modify your original function to output the correct result to begin with?

Comment: @Nick I'm laughing because apparently yes it is possible and it took me a total of 2 minutes to do. Nevertheless the question I posted above still somewhat stands; it would be nice to know how to solve the problem in Regex if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially to solve this you need recursion, or more simply, keep applying the regex in a loop until the replacement doesn't change the input string. For example using your regex from https://regex101.com/r/Yl1IJv/4:

```
s = '{{ab},{ab,ab}}'
while True:
    news = re.sub(r'(?P<first>.?(\w+|\d+).?),(?P=first)', r'\g<1>', s, 0)
    if news == s:
        break
    s = news
print(s)
```

Output

```
{{ab}}
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/ATWGL3129)

With

```
s = '{{{{x},{x,x}}},{{{x},{x,x}},x}}'
```

The output is

```
{{{{x}}},{{{x}},x}}
```

as required. [Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/PNGNOG92135)